# Exporting global functions from multiple projects in Windows DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dllexport

I have a similar setup as described below:

**Project A**

- Windows DLL
- Depends on **Project B**

**Project B**

- Compiled as static library

Now, if a global function, e.g. `createNewFoo` is compiled in **Project B**, it is never exported into the final DLL, although it is declared with `dllexport` and the final application uses it as `dllimport`:

```
namespace example
{
class __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
  Foo();
};

__declspec(dllexport) Foo* createNewFoo();

}

}
```

Note that, the class `Foo` is always exported into the final DLL, its only global or static functions that are somehow discarded.

Furthermore, note that the same global function is always exported if it is compiled in **Project A** instead of **Project B**.

Is there any setting in Visual Studio 2010 that allows exporting of global or static functions from dependent projects? or this is a limitation of the tools?

Comment: static library do not need dllexport, you just need include Project B's h and lib in project A

Comment: This is exactly what I do, the project B's header is included in project A, and project B's lib is statically linked in project A.

Comment: for static lib, it means all B's functions is imported into DLL A.

Comment: What error do you get if you try to call the function from outside the .dll? + Can you call it fine from the .dll itself?

Comment: Yes, the function can be used inside the DLL, but not from external DLL or application. I get the following linker error:
unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport) class example::Foo * __cdecl example::createNewFoo(void)"

Comment: you should export the function in DLL when you use it.

Comment: It is declared as dllexport in DLL project.

Answer (score 1):

Using a static library is a great way to reuse code. Rather than re-implementing the same routines in every app that requires the functionality, you write them one time in a static library and then reference it from the apps. Code linked from a static library becomes part of your app—you don’t have to install another file to use the code.

As you case, Lib B's function is linked and become a part of DLL A, if you want to export these function in DLL A, you should **explicitly** `dllexport` function in DLL A, and in function body, you can call Lib B's function to reuse code.

Comment: The function is explicitly declared as dllexport in **Project A** by including the same header file.

Comment: you should also implement createNewFoo() function body in **Project A**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Implementing createNewFoo also in **Project A** helped. However, I would like to know the reason why it was not exported in the DLL, while class Foo was?

Comment: If you declare a function or object with the dllexport attribute, its definition must appear in some module of the same program. Otherwise, a linker error is generated.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10.aspx

Comment: The definition is present in Project B, which is compiled as a module of project A? Why I have to move the definition to project A?

Comment: because you export in Projece A which is a DLL, so you should move the definition to Project A. For Lib, who link it can use its defition.